# Is $(a,b)/(b)$ equal to $(a)/(b)$?

Tags: ring-theory

I'm doing ring theory, and I'm trying to understand quotients and ideals a little bit better.

I was playing around a little bit with definitions. Can I say that this is true:

$(a,b)/(b)$ = $(a)/(b)$ ?

I think it is true because. If $x + (b) \in (a,b)/(b)$. Then $x=ar_1 + br_2$ for $r_1,r_2\in R$. And $ar_1 + br_2 + (b) = ar_1 + (b)$. Does $x+(b) \in (a)/(b)$.

And if $y+(b) \in (a)/(b)$. Then $y=ar_1$. Then $y=ar_1 + b⋅0$. Then $y + (b) \in (a,b)/(b)$.

But if I consider $ℤ/7ℤ=(3ℤ,7ℤ)/7ℤ=3ℤ/7ℤ$. Than it seems not to hold. Where does my reasoning fail ?

Comment: You can't form $3\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, since $7\mathbb{Z}\not\subseteq 3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You have to be careful with the meaning of $(b)$. In $(a,b)/(b)$. On the left hand side, $(a,b)$ is an $R$-module, $(b)$ is an $R$-submodule. On the right hand side $(a)$ is an $R$-module, but $(b)$ need not be an $R$-submodule of $(a)$. It does work if you write $(a) \cap (b)$ on the right hand side, though.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $15 \in 3\mathbb Z$ and $15 = 1 \pmod 7$ so the elements of $3\mathbb Z$, when taken modulo $7$, do generate $\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$.

You are correct that both the ideals $(a, b)$ and $(a)$ project to the same ideal in $R/(b)$.  The reason it looks weird is that the ideal $(a)$ doesn't need to contain the ideal $(b)$.  For this reason people usually prefer the notation $(a, b)/(b)$ or $\frac{(a) + (b)}{(b)}$ instead of $(a)/(b)$.