# Is the quotient $R/(a,b)$ equal to first quotienting $R$ with $(a)$ and then with $(b)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the quotient $R/(a,b)$ equal to first quotienting with $(a)$ and then with $(b)$?

I've been thinking about this for some time. And I think the following is true:

$$\frac{R}{(a,b)}=\frac{R/(a)}{(a,b)/(a)}\overset{(1)}{=}\frac{R/(a)}{(b)/(a)}=\frac{R/(a)}{bR/aR}\overset{(2)}{=}\frac{R/(a)}{b (R/aR)}=\frac{R/(a)}{[b]}$$

where I define $[b]$ as the ideal generated by $b$ in the ring $R/aR$. So this seems true. For (1), I [already](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525033/is-a-b-b-equal-to-a-b) asked a question. And for (2) I think it is true, but not yet able to proof it. How can I proof that $b(R/aR)=bR/aR$ ?

Answer (score 2):

What you have is that $(R/(a))/(\overline{b}) \cong R/(a,b)$, where $\overline{b}$ denotes the reduction of $b$ mod $(a)$, i.e. $\overline{b} = b + (a)$ as an element of $R/(a)$.  The isomorphism is induced from the natural map $R / (a) \rightarrow R / (a,b)$ which sends $x + (a)$ to $x + (a,b)$.  You need to check that this is a well-defined homomorphism, that it is surjective, and that the kernel is equal to $(\overline{b})$.  Then apply the Fundamental Theorem of Ring Homomorphisms to obtain the conclusion stated in the first sentence.

Comment: If $x\in(\bar{b})$. Then $x = r\bar{b}$ with $r\in R$. Then $x=r(b+(a))$. Then $x=rb+(a)$. Then $\varphi(x)=rb+(a)+(b)$. Then $\varphi(x)=0+(a)+(b)$. Therefore $x$ in the kernel. Something like this ?

Comment: Yes, but you also need to prove the converse - if $\phi(x) = 0$, then $x \in (\overline{b})$.

Comment: I can use the exact same steps right ? Only in reverse order. I understand your answer now. But I still don't know if the reasoning in my post is valid.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is fine.

Comment: So it is true that $b(R/aR)=bR/aR$ ?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.  I meant that your reasoning in your first comment to my answer is fine.  For the original post, no, some of what you wrote does not make sense.  For example, what does $bR / aR$ mean?  You are treating it like a quotient ring, even though $bR$ is not a ring and $aR$ is not necessarily contained in $bR$.  You need to give a proof based on ideas, not just meaningless strings of symbols.

Comment: $bR$ is a ring right. It is subring of $R$ as it is a (normal) subgroup and closed under multiplication.

Comment: So what is written in this answer is not right ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525033/is-a-b-b-equal-to-a-b?lq=1

Comment: True $bR$ is a ring since I presume you are stipulating that $R$ is a commutative ring.  Jim's answer explains why something like $(a)/(b)$ is not a good notation and that what you probably mean by it is probably $(a,b)/(b)$.  So they are equal, but only because one is defined to be the other, since it does not make sense on its own right.